# Best method to save javascript data in pdf format

Tags: javascript, csv, pdf

I have a requirement to save javascript data ( which i converted to array format ) and save it in csv, txt and pdf formats. while i could do it easily at client side for csv and txt format. I would like to know the best way to do it for the pdf formats. I tried searching online but of no much help. Any inputs are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Part of code i used to save JS data in csv :

```
var pom = document.createElement('a');
pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(finalVal));
pom.setAttribute('download', fname);
pom.click();
```

Comment: clearly didn't search hard enough

Answer (score 1):

jsPDF will do what you need. Once set up, all you need to do is feed it your data in string format. I have used it in the past to achieve nearly the exact same thing you are trying to accomplish.

You can download the plugin here: https://parall.ax/products/jspdf